# How to create custom camera rectangle

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to have camera small in screen smartphone rectangle, Can you help me?  thanks all same pictures

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I'm finding it difficult to understand your question. Are you saying that you want a part of the screen on your smartphone application to display what the camera is seeing?